# IOS programming: Passing large arrays over segues, good or bad idea?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue

I am relatively new to IOS development and throughout my application I have been passing a lot of information between my view controller segues. I am currently getting this data from a cloud database and I am worried as time goes on the data I will be passing over my segues will increase as the cloud data increases. Is it a bad idea to pass large amounts of data over these segues, how will it affect the performance of my application if I will eventually pass relatively large arrays over these segues (1,000 to 2,000 elements)? What else can I do if this is a bad idea? Suggestions, tips, pointers would all be great. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are just passing the pointer to strong/retaining property this will not have a negative effect on the performance — just a pointer is set, it doesnt matter how the object looks like.

Assume this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"otherSegue"]) {
        OtherViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.dataArray = self.downloadedArray;
    }
}
```

As long as the property `dataArray` on `otherViewController` is strong or retaining (`@property (strong) NSArray *dataArray;`), the execution time of that code should not increase with the size of the array, as just a pointer is passed.

Comment: this is discussed thousands of times. please search for it. (and accept my answer if it answered your question)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use storyboards, but a [quick look on google](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) pointed to something:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```